# Design of a Decentralized Twitter

Tags: architecture, twitter, communication, p2p, one-to-many

Twitter is a popular social networking service where users can write short messages in a one-to-many fashion (you can read more about it at Wikipedia). I've been reading an interesting article by Alex Payne (former API Lead at Twitter), [*The Very Last Thing I’ll Write About Twitter*](http://al3x.net/2010/09/15/last-thing-about-twitter.html), where he argues for a decentralized one-to-many communications mechanism...

From a programming perspective, how would this service be designed? I imagine it could be similar to email, where anyone can set up a mail server. However, one of the major motivations is to resist censorship; can the architecture be *fully* decentralized? It would involve a similar protocol to the open standards-based protocols behind email and IM; does such a protocol already exist? Should the design include aspects of an anonymity network such as Tor? Has an open-source initiative already begun for this?

I'm making this a community wiki, as these are rather open-ended questions about the design of a decentralized one-to-many communication service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's like email but with more of a graph-processing stack (following).

Answer (score 1):

Blogs are already in that format (with RSS to make it a more formal protocol)